# Missing Firebase app_update events

Tags: firebase-analytics, android-tv

I'm seeing huge difference for `app_update` events automatically sent by Firebase and real conversion of user base to newer version when it's released.

For example 5 days during release of new version: 120 events VS 3k users (x20 difference)

[image: app_update events]
[image: users app's version]

I did check another "alpha" update with data exported to BigQuery:

Count `app_update` events (to **any** version):

```
SELECT
  COUNT(user_pseudo_id)
FROM
  `analytics_151378081.events_*`
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190820' AND '20190827' AND 
  event_name = "app_update"
```

```
---|---
1  | 49
```

Count users with **new** version who's first app launch was before this version was pushed to alpha:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT(user_pseudo_id))
FROM
  `analytics_151378081.events_*`
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190820' AND '20190827' 
  AND app_info.version = "0.4.2.1" 
  AND user_first_touch_timestamp < 1566259200000000
```

```
--|---
1 | 73
```

So it's 49 events (to any version) VS 73 "old" users using **new** version.

Is anyone seeing the same? 
My platform is AndroidTV and a lot of sessions do not have UI (TV Input Framework integration through *service*)