# Few app_update events for Android

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

When a new version of the app was updated I noticed Firebase event app_update rarely was counted.

On the other hand, app_remove and first_open present a high volume of occurrence.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Why did this happen? The event app_update doesn't as it should?

The IOS metrics for this event behave normally.

version: com.google.firebase:firebase-core -> 16.0.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience it's broken and it does not report events reliably. Here is my question about same problem: [Missing Firebase app_update events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57686686/missing-firebase-app-update-events)

My application is a bit different from standard (most of the time it starts as service inside other system app), so my guess was that it can be related to missing events.